# Wordpress Query Custom Post Types

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type called **Food Menu** to which I add items like:

- Soup Of The Day
- Steak Dinner
- Tuna Sandwich
- Ice Cream

I've also created **Menu Item Types** as follows:

- Lunch Menu
- Set Dinner Menu
- À La Carte Dinner Menu
- Children's Menu

I've also created **Tags** for each menu item post as follows:

- Starters
- Mains
- Sandwiches
- Desserts

I am trying to figure out a way to query the posts so that when I click on the **Lunch Menu** page it will list out all the post items as follows:

**Lunch Menu**

**Starters**
Soup Of The Day
Spring Roll
Scampi

**Mains**
Steak Dinner
Fish & Chips
Pasta Dish

**Sandwiches**
Tuna Sandwich
Chicken
Beef Sandwich

**Desserts**
Apple Pie
Ice Cream
Cake

An item like "Soup Of The Day" needs to be available in both Lunch Menu, Set Dinner Menu and À La Carte Dinner Menu using the tag Starters.

I've seen some Wordpress portfolio pages being sorted/filtered by Tags so I'm wondering how this can be achieved or is this the solution for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are "Menu Item Types" a custom taxonomy? Are items like "Soup Of The Day" given multiple taxonomies, since they are available all day?

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for the reply, yes Menu Item Types is a custom taxonomy and "Soup Of The Day" is given multiple taxonomies like: soup, starter, appetiser etc.